# Полукруг, направленный прямой стороной к верху, а выпуклой к низу

Tags: android, xml, drawable

Я не знаю как сделать полукруг, выпуклый снизу, который я собираюсь закрасить градиентом и увеличивать с помощью аниматора.

---

1. *Прямоугольник с закруглёнными углами мне не подошел, потому что я не смог при анимации менять их радиус.*
2. *`android:top="-50"` круг не обрезает.*

Comment: Попробуйте: https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/know-percent-support-library/en с -50% margin_top

Comment: @iFr0z Я имел виду обычный полукруг, направленный прямой стороной к верху, а выпуклой - к низу

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**drawable/clipcircle.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<clip
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:clipOrientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="bottom">

    <shape android:shape="oval">

        <gradient
            android:startColor="#6586F0"
            android:centerColor="#D6D6D6"
            android:endColor="#4B6CD6"
            android:angle="90"/>

    </shape>

</clip>
```

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*
import android.animation.ObjectAnimator
import android.animation.PropertyValuesHolder

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        semicircle_v.background.level = 5000 // in Java: findViewById(R.id.semicircle_v).getBackground().setLevel(5000);

        pulseAnimation()
    }

    private fun pulseAnimation() {
        val scaleDown = ObjectAnimator.ofPropertyValuesHolder(
            semicircle,
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleX", 1.2f),
            PropertyValuesHolder.ofFloat("scaleY", 1.2f)
        )
        scaleDown.duration = 310
        scaleDown.repeatCount = ObjectAnimator.INFINITE
        scaleDown.repeatMode = ObjectAnimator.REVERSE
        scaleDown.start()
    }
}
```

**layout/activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/semicircle_v"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/clipcircle" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**Результат:**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

[clipDrawable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/ClipDrawable): `level` увеличивается в диапазоне `[0; 10000]`, где `0 = скрытый - 10000 = полностью отображается`, аля `volume`.